# Iterate over an array of integers using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I don't think this question fits in the context of angular.Am having an array of integers `var myArray=[1,2,3,4,5]`.Is it possible to do a ng-repeat and display the integers on `myArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myArray">{{i}}</div>``
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myArray track by $index">
    {{ i }}
</div>
```

The [relevant documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates), BTW, shows an example doing what you want.

And of course, the array must be in the $scope, not just declared as a local variable of your controller.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need place that variable inside scope variable then only you could use it on html.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in myArray">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tRxzr/712/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also code as below:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
 {{$index + 1}}
</div>
```

Comment: what if "i in [1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 10]" ? :)